# template class method in source file

Tags: c++, templates

I've got header file with template class:

```
#ifndef BUBBLE_H
#define BUBBLE_H

#include "algorithm.h"

template <typename T>
class Bubble : public Algorithm <T> {
public:

    Bubble(T* in, int inSize) : Algorithm<T>(in, inSize){}

    void compute();
};

#endif // BUBBLE_H
```

if I put whole body of compute() class here everything works fine. But I would like to have it in cpp file. I wrote:

```
#include "bubbleSort.h" using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void BubbleSort<T>::compute(){   //(*)
    for (int i = 1; i<this->dataSize; i++){
        for (int j = this->dataSize-1; j>=i; j--){
            if(this->data[j] < this->data[j-1]) swap(this->data[j-1], this->data[j]);
        }
    } }
```

But I received error in line (*):

> error: expected initializer before '<' token  void
>   BubbleSort::compute(){
>              ^

How I should fix it?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're mixing up `Bubble` and `BubbleSort`, probably also the headers `bubble.h` and `bubbleSort.h`.

Comment: Oh my gosh! That's so embarassing o.O Thanks a lot :D